# Copy game files from one installation of Steam to another

Tags: games, steam

I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed on both my desktop PC and my laptop. After downloading *Crypt of the Necrodancer* on my desktop, I thought I could just copy the folder of that game which is located in *~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common* to a USB stick and then copy it from there to that directory on my laptop. The purpose for this was to avoid downloading 1.5 GB of data a second time. However, Steam just gives me the option to install the game, upon choosing which it says something like *discovering existing game files*. Then the files are just removed and Steam starts downloading them anew. Is there a way to keep these files?

Comment: `steamapps` contains the manifest of games as text files with numbers  (ie. appmanifest_440.sf)  this is where Steam looks to see if a game is installed you should try to just move the whole `steamapps` folder and see if that helps.  I have done this from a backup(a disk backup not a steam one) and it worked. It should not require the finding existing files step. If not the answer below will work but it comes with some issues; it only backs up the games, any download content in the games (maps and mods) will not be backed up and you will have to download them again when you need them.

Comment: @TrailRider: Maybe you could post this as an alternative answer. I would upvote it, though I guess I'll keep the first answer as the accepted one since it achieved just what I needed.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer b/c I am not sure it still works.  I use 14.04 so things may have changed.  It should still but without conformation, I don't want to post it as an answer.  It should still work but I know that the answer provided below would work, I will leave it as a comment, it might be a good thing to try first but if that fails, your accepted answer will work....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used to do it that way but for some reason it's no longer a reliable method. The good news is Steam has a built in backup/restore feature that works a lot better. You can choose to backup directly to your USB stick.

Click the **Steam** menu and choose **Backup and Restore Games**.

[image: Backup/Restore]

Comment: Okay, I'll try it.